# Change the Color of Ybar

Tags: tikz-pgf, ybar

I used the ybar from this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273817/pgfplots-drawing-a-histogram) and it fits absolutly my needs except the color.

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
 
% Bar chart drawing library 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[ybar interval, ymax=5,ymin=0, minor y tick num = 3]
        \addplot coordinates { (1, 2) (2, 4) (3, 5) (4, 4) (5, 2) (6, 0) };
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in this chart:

[image]

I now want to change the color of each bar, but my initial approach with splitting each bar as a single `\addplot` didn't worked.

Any Idea to change the colors?

Answer (score 6):

I feel this plain TikZ way is more flexible for users. In fact, other commands is for decorations; you just need one loop `\foreach`

```
\foreach \i/\j/\color in {1/2/cyan,2/4.5/magenta,3/5.1/teal,4/2.5/violet,5/3.5/orange}
\draw[line width=8mm,color=\color] (\i,0)--+(90:\j);
```

Use `line width=10mm` if you want no-gap between color columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!30] (0,0) grid[xstep=0] (6,5.5);
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \path (\i,0) node[below] {$\i$};
\foreach \j in {0,.2,...,5.5} \draw (0,\j)--+(.1,0);    
\foreach \j in {0,...,5} \path (0,\j) node[left] {$\j$};    
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (6,5.5);

\foreach \i/\j/\color in {1/2/cyan,2/4.5/magenta,3/5.1/teal,4/2.5/violet,5/3.5/orange}
\draw[line width=8mm,color=\color] (\i,0)--+(90:\j);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** adding numbers for the heights of each column. I found that TikZ/TeX is not comfortable with  the *coincidence* naming `[color=\color]`, so I change to `[color=\icolor]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
\draw[gray!30] (0,0) grid[xstep=0] (6,6);
\foreach \j in {0,.2,...,6} \draw (0,\j)--+(.1,0);    
\foreach \j in {0,...,5} \path (0,\j) node[left] {$\j$};    
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);

\foreach \i/\j/\icolor in {1/2/cyan,2/4.5/magenta,3/5.1/teal,4/2.5/violet,5/3.5/orange}
\draw[line width=8mm,color=\icolor] 
(\i,0) node[below=-4mm,black] {$\i$}
--(\i,\j) node[above=-4mm]{$\j$};
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initial solution is how it works. Is this what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          minor y tick num = 3,
          ybar=0cm,
          bar width=1cm,
          ymin=0,
          ymax=7,
          ylabel=values,
          xtick=data,
          xticklabels={My bar chart},
         ]                 
\addplot[draw=cyan, fill=cyan] coordinates {(1, 2) };
\addplot[draw=magenta, fill=magenta] coordinates {(1, 4) };
\addplot[draw=green, fill=green] coordinates {(1, 5) };
\addplot[draw=yellow, fill=yellow] coordinates {(1, 4) };
\addplot[draw=gray, fill=gray] coordinates {(1, 3) };
\addplot[draw=orange, fill=orange] coordinates {(1, 1) };
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: This is somehow similar to my dirty solution, which I tried in the meantime. But your solution struggles with xticklabels. I cheated on the xticks a bit and renamed them. But still feels dirty

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by **@onpra7**'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240826/132778), another `\foreach` loop drawing each bar:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=5.5,
    minor y tick num = 3,
  ]
    \foreach \x/\y/\color in {
      1/2/cyan,
      2/4/magenta,
      3/5/green,
      4/4/yellow,
      5/2/gray,
      6/0/orange
    } {
      \edef\mybar{\noexpand\addplot[fill=\color]
        coordinates {(\x-0.5,0) (\x-0.5,\y) (\x+0.5,\y) (\x+0.5,0)} --cycle;
      }\mybar
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]